# How to Free Memory in Mysql C++ Connector correctly?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am wondering how I can free memory allocated by Mysql C++ Connector correctly. 
In their code example they do not do this correctly as far as I can see:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html

They delete the created objects only in the try block, but not in the catch. So for my code I added a delete statement in the catch block. But this not working stable. Most of the time the time the catch blog runs fine, but in some cases the program crashes with a "double Free" or "Segmentation Fault" within the catch blog. So I just removed the delete for now and it is working.

But what is the best way to do it? 
My code (with free) looked like this:

```
...

sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;

bool connect()
{
    driver=sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    try
    {
        con = driver->connect(server, user, password);
        con->setSchema(database);
    } catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {

        std::cout << "Error connecting to the Database: " << e.what() << endl;
        if (con != NULL)
            delete con;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void disconnect()
{
    delete con;
    con = NULL;
}



bool update() {

    sql::PreparedStatement *stmt = NULL;
    sql::ResultSet *res = NULL;
    bool ret;
    int value;


        if (!connect())
            return false;

        try
        {
            stmt =      con->prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id=?;");
            stmt->setInt64(1, 123ull);

            res = stmt->executeQuery();
            if (!res->first())
                ret = false;
            else
            {
                value=res->getInt("value");
                std::cout<< value <<endl;
                ret = true;

                delete stmt;
                stmt=NULL;

                stmt = con->prepareStatement("UPDATE table1 SET value=? WHERE id=?;");
                value++;
                stmt->setInt(1, value);
                stmt->setInt64(2, 123ull);
                stmt->executeQuery();

            }
        } catch (sql::SQLException &e)
        {

            std::cout << "Error executing Query: " << e.what();
            if (stmt != NULL)
                delete stmt;
            if (res != NULL)
                delete res;


            disconnect();
            return false;
        }

        delete stmt;
        delete res;
        disconnect();
        return ret;

}
```

It seems to have problems especially when the `excecuteQuery()` throws an exception, sometimes no result Object is created.

Answer (score 0):

Since the snippet is different from the actual code - which wrongfully used `free`  instead of `delete` - unfortunately l could not deduce the source of problem.
Nevertheless, **RAII** is specifically recommended to avoid such cases and confusions. I would use **`std::unique_ptr`** instead of ***raw pointer*** as the starting point. Header is **`<memory>`** and you'd not need any action to delete the pointers. Instead of `disconnect()` you can simply reset `con`:

```
sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver* driver;
std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> con;
try{
    driver = (sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance());
    con.reset(driver->connect(server, user, password));
}
...
con.reset(nullptr);//instead of disconnect
```

The doc referenced in the OP states that the driver shall not be explicitly deleted; the connector would implicitly take care of it. In other words, driver is owned by connector.